# Swizzling methods : Programmatically dismiss system dialogs like “<App> would like to access your contacts” in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, ios10

Is there a way to programmatically dismiss dialogs like the ones where the app wants to access contacts?

I think there's a way by swizzling API methods, but I don't really know which. What is the methodology to find out which methods need to be swizzled? If swizzling is not the way then what could be another alternative?

As a note, this is not for a product, is just for testing so swizzling is a good option if it works.Kindly share sample code if any.

Comment: I honestly hope there isn't a way to do that. If you discover one, please tell Apple, so that they could close the security hole.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way to do that. The security notices are presented by the system UI Window Server, not the app itself.

This is done for security, so what you're trying to do totally negates the whole point of them popping up in the first place.